# prove sequence is increasing or deacreasing and bounded or unbounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove if the following sequence is inc. or decrea. and then if it is bounded.

So this is the sequence:$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n}{n^2+1}$$.
Now I really don’t know how to prove this.But this is how I would go about this problem.So we know that if a sequence converges then it’s bounded.The limit of this thing is 0, therefore it’s bounded.But how do I evaluate the bounds?I would take the derivative which would come out to be increasing for -1<x<1.Therefore we can conclude that 1 is the least upper bound of this sequence.I don’t really know if this is correct, so please point out any logical mistake.The lower bound is clearly 0(numerator and denominator can just be positive).But I have also seen some proofs by induction.Could someone show me the whole proof by induction?I have seen proofs when the sequence is strictly increasing or decreasing but in this case the behaviour of the base case isn’t obvious.Can we say $$a_{1} > a_{0}$$ and then conclude the opposite(that the function is not monotonous)?Thank you for checking my work and and attempting to clear my doubts.

Comment: Hint:  Compute $a_{n+1} - a_n$, and show that it is negative for all positive $n$, thus proving that it is a decreasing sequence.  Since the sequence is positive and decreasing, it is bounded from above and below.  $a_1$ would be its upper bound, and $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n $ is its lower bound.

Comment: @GeometryLover just one more question: how can I prove that a sequence is alternating or non-alternating

Comment: Find the ratio $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.  If the ratio is always negative, then the sequence is alternating, otherwise it is non-alternating.

Comment: THANKS @GeometryLover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$0\leq \frac{2n}{n^2+1}\leq \frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}<2$$

Hence $a_n=\frac{2n}{n^2+1}$ is bounded by $2$

For show that $a_n$ is increasing you should prove that
$$a_{n}<a_{n+1}$$

it is $$ \frac{2n}{n^2+1}< \frac{2(n+1)}{(n+1)^2+1}$$

Comment: thank you it makes sense

Comment: You´re welcome!